# Disable notification popups on Ubuntu 17.10/Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, 17.10, notification, gnome-shell

As you can see on this image, there is an option to turn off notification popups:
[image]

But it doesn't work. I have tried turning it on and off again but I still get those annoying popups.

What do I have to do to get rid of them?